# Bars on second X Axis not showing

Tags: chart.js

In the following JsFiddle the second dataset is not showing up when setting xAxisID to "2". It works when set to "1" or commented out:

https://jsfiddle.net/8v0xwj9L/3/

```
  labels: ["Label1", "Label2", "Label3", "Label4", "Label5"],
  datasets: [{
      "label": "Total V",
      "backgroundColor": "rgba(53,81,103,1)",
      "borderColor": "rgba(53,81,103,.4)",
      "data": [10, 4, 3, 7, 6]
    },
    {
      "label": "Total C",
      "xAxisID": "2",
      "backgroundColor": "rgba(255,153,0,1)",
      "borderColor": "rgba(255,153,0,.4)",
      "data": [9, 9, 8, 7, 6]
    }
  ]
};

var options = {
  scales: {
    xAxes: [{
        id: "1",
        position: 'bottom'
      },
      {
        offset: true,
        id: '2',
        position: 'bottom'
      }
    ],
  }
};


var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
new Chart(ctx, {
  type: "bar",
  data: data,
  options: options
});
```

What could be the reason?

My end goal is to have a bar chart with 2 datasets that have different ranges on the X axis but still overlap in the graph.

Imagine comparing datapoints from Week 1 with Week 2 by showing a bar for next to each other for each day in the week but their X timestamps obviously don't match hence two X axis.

Answer (score 0):

When you say timestamps, are we talking about days or times? If it's just days, you can use one x-axis like here: https://jsfiddle.net/jbmn01z6/

If you want time, then a bar chart is not a good idea. I don't even know if it's possible the way you would like it. I would use a line chart with a x-axis of the `type: 'time'`. Then you can use and show your timestamps very precisely.

Comment: Using one X Axis with manually specified labels using either the weekday (Mon Tue etc) or day of the month (1st 2nd) etc would be a last resort.  But this doesn't answer why a bar that is set for a second X axis suddenly disappears. It seems that it works with line charts though.

Comment: Can't edit the first comment so here another one: I'd still like to understand why bars on a second X axis are simply invisible. No errors. When changing the graph type to lines the second dataset becomes visible again.

Comment: Because there's no use case for that. Bar charts are for category axis, and you don't need bars between categories. If you want to use different timestamps, you have a linear axis which doesn't work with a bar chart. It's simply as that. If I completly misunderstand your use case, please post an image/drawing or anything but I don't see a point in using a bar chart for your case...